# Extra content at the end of the document While generating xml from Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, xml

I am trying to render a xml on a VF page with `contentType="text/xml"` but I am getting an error in **Chrome**

[image]

**Error in Firefox**
`XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: https://letscreatecustomdomainname-dev-ed--sii.ap6.visual.force.com/apex/PackageXMLGenerator?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1&core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1
Line Number 1, Column 228:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><products><product><Name>Xbox One</Name><Code>XBO</Code></product><product><Name>PlayStation 4</Name><Code>PS4</Code></product><product><Name>WII</Name><Code>Wii</Code></product></products><script type="text/javascript">  SfdcApp.Visualforce.viewstate.ViewstateSender.sendViewstate('https://letscreatecustomdomainname-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com', 'sii__PackageXMLGenerator');  </script>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^`

I am getting some out put as well but it's missing all the tags. I can see a proper xml in debug. Below is my code. Please guide me what might be the reason.

**Apex Class to Generate the XML**

```
public class PackageXMLGeneratorController {
    public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
    public string csvAsString{get;set;}

    public string xmlstring { get; set;}

    public PackageXMLGeneratorController(){
        DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();

        dom.XmlNode products = doc.createRootElement('products', null, null);
        dom.XmlNode body1= products.addChildElement('product', null, null);

        body1.addChildElement('Name', null, null).addTextNode('Xbox One');
        body1.addChildElement('Code', null, null).addTextNode('XBO');

        dom.XmlNode body2= products.addChildElement('product', null, null);

        body2.addChildElement('Name', null, null).addTextNode('PlayStation 4');
        body2.addChildElement('Code', null, null).addTextNode('PS4');

        dom.XmlNode body3= products.addChildElement('product', null, null);

        body3.addChildElement('Name', null, null).addTextNode('WII');
        body3.addChildElement('Code', null, null).addTextNode('Wii');

        xmlstring = doc.toXmlString();
        System.debug('========>'+xmlstring);
    }

    public ApexPages.PageReference downloadXML( ) {
        return Page.PackageXMLDownload;
    }
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="PackageXMLGeneratorController" contentType="text/xml;filename.xml">
  <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!xmlstring}" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get it working *just right*, you need to pay careful attention to extra line breaks in your code. I created the following in my org:

```
<apex:page controller="q203222" contentType="text/xml;myfile.xml" showHeader="false">{!content}</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class q203222 {
    public String getContent() {
        Dom.Document d = new Dom.Document();
        d.createRootElement('test',null,null);
        d.getRootElement().addChildElement('data',null,null);
        return d.toXmlString();
    }
}
```

---

Do not use apex:outputText, and do not have more than 1 line in your page. It must look basically identical to this pattern in order to not have errors while parsing.